# Hide Content on ASP.NET page besides using Panel

Tags: asp.net

I have some limitations in terms of using the the ASP.NET Panel:

```
    <asp:Panel>
```

The issue is that I cannot use a Panel within a Panel based on how we got some items programmed.

Wondering what else I can use inside of a Panel to hide info. I tried using a DIV but that did not work.

```
    <div id="myDIV" runat="server"></div>

     myDIV.Visible = false;
```

Comment: How did you use the `DIV`, how did you try to *hide* it?

Comment: Where in the code-behind are you setting ` myDIV.Visible = false;`, if you're using an update panel, then the code may not be hit?

Comment: Did this work? you don't seem to respond to anyone that helps with your questions?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This would work...

```
<div>Some text</div> <!-- text you can see -->
<br />
<div class="hidden">Some text</div> <!-- text hidden based on class of div -->
```

CSS

```
.hidden {
    display: none;
}
```

see [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/axxr6tpq/)